# How to identify an HTML element in Typescript in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a div element and I need to find the element and apply some logic over it, how can I identify that element without jQuery or javascript??

generally in jquery we do 
$('#elementID') but in typescript??

I tried below ways

```
<div #myID></div>
```

in ts file

```
@ViewChild('myID') myDiv: any;
```

and when I use

```
let element = this.myDiv.nativeElement
```

I'm getting my div directly and I cannot apply any operations on it again I have to write

```
let element = $(this.myDiv.nativeElement)
```

to apply any changes on that element

I tried declaring it as HTMLElement instead any and other ways .

Can any one help , how to find an element apply functions on it as we do in jquery without using **$**

Comment: You should explain what you want to achieve because accessing DOM elements directly is most of the time not the most elegant way you can use in angular2.

Comment: which type of changes you wants to apply on element?

Comment: Actually I'm using third party framework and I have to implement its custom methods on it  after identifying the element.

Comment: See my [angular2 wrapper](https://github.com/seveves/ng2-vis/blob/master/components/network/vis-network.directive.ts) of vis.js ... there I identify the network element as 'any' and call the methods on it (no type safety of course).

Answer (score 0):

In angular 2 we use function or $event to provide logic.
for example-

> (click)="func()" or (ngModelChange)="func($event)".